# JAVA APACHE POI: Getting a "We found a problem with some content in *.xlsx. Do you want us to try to recover it as much as we can" error

Tags: java, apache-poi

We're trying to generate excel files, and I'm running into the above error when trying to execute this code -

I've tried using `CreationHelper`, and also tried `FileOutputStream`. But, nothing seems to work. We're using apache poi - 4.0.1

```html
XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = excelDownloadService.createSheetForBudget(type, campaignId, duration);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            xssfWorkbook.write(bos);

            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Budget.Report_" + LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMddyy")) + ".xlsx");
            xssfWorkbook.write(response.getOutputStream());

            xssfWorkbook.close();
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
            response.getOutputStream().close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the `Name` attribute elsewhere to name the worksheet. After removing that, it worked.

```html
final Name name = xssfWorkbook.createName();
        name.setNameName("Summary.Report_" + LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMddyy")) + ".xlsx");
```